# How to get a number that follows after certain word from url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a URL from which I need to read a value. I need to take out the step from the URL. I want to write regex to do that

Let say that if I get the `window.location.href`, I get the following result

```
https://mypage/route/step-1/more-route/
https://mypage/route/step-5/more-route/
```

I want to get the step using regex. What is the best way to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: `s.split("/")[4]` or `.match(/^(?:.*?\/){4}(.+?)\//)` might work, but If you post the actual URL with more specifics about where `step-n` might be and all of your possible edge cases, the prior operation can likely be improved significantly to match your use. What are all the requirements at hand? Thanks.

Comment: If the URLs all look like that, just grab one or more digits between a dash and a slash. Pretty straightforward, as regular expressions go.

Comment: When you say step are you looking for a result of `step-1` or `1`?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn question heading clearly suggest that you need to get number after certain word

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace to replace everything except for the `step` number:

```
.+\/step-(\d+)\/.+
```

```js
const url1 = 'https://mypage/route/step-1/more-route/'
const url2 = 'https://mypage/route/step-5/more-route/'
const url3 = 'https://mypage/route/step-13/more-route/'

const step = (url) => url.replace(/.+\/step-(\d+)\/.+/, '$1')

console.log(step(url1))
console.log(step(url2))
console.log(step(url3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
\/step-(\d+)
```

- `\/` - Matches `/`
- `step-` - Matches word `step-`
- `(\d+)` - Matches one or more digits (captured group)

```js
let urls = ['https://mypage/route/step-1/more-route/'
,'https://mypage/route/step-5/more-route/']

let getStep = (url) => {
  let match = url.match(/\/step-(\d+)/i)
  return match && match[1]
}

urls.forEach(url=> console.log(getStep(url)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it up and then use the index.

`let address = window.location.href;
 let addressArray= address.split('/')
 console.log(addressArray[3])`